# How do I send notifications from Google Cloud(GCP) via Firebase to an Android app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I know how to send messages from Firebase cloud messaging portal to an android device. But my server runs on Google Cloud, I do `gcloud app deploy` from my local machine and the app logic gets deployed on Google Cloud. Now, I want to send notifications, based on the data stored as Entities in GCP Datastore, to an Android App.

Notification messages can be sent from Firestore-Cloud Messaging portal to an Android device, if I could harness this Firestore Cloud Messaging API in my GCP logic, then my problem will be solved.

I'm trying to look for any examples or POC's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/how-to) to add such custom functionality...
for example: https://android.jlelse.eu/serverless-notifications-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-685d7c327cd4

and there are [Cloud Datastore Callbacks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/callbacks), which can be used as event triggers. most relevant for Cloud Functions might be the [Google Cloud Datastore Node.js Client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.4.x/) - in order to connect to the Datastore. here's [one of my examples](https://github.com/syslogic/google-apps-script/blob/master/CloudDatastore.gs), it is written in AppScript (similar to Node.js), which also connects to a Cloud Datastore, with the service account JSON loaded from Google Drive.

however, in this case the Datastore would need to subsequently trigger an [HTTP Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) or Pub/Sub Trigger and the code behind that trigger could get more data from the Datastore or directly send the Firebase notification.

in Cloud Function there are just triggers for [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage), while the [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) (publish/subscribe) triggers can be used for just anything. The Datastore would need to publish whatever event (add/edit/update/delete) - while a Cloud Functions script would need to subscribe these events.

using Firebase as backend might be less effort, because data-change events/triggers are being supported out-of-the-box, without any HTTP interaction or Pub/Sub communication involved.

Comment: Not that its an issue but do we really need to use service account JSON file? I mean can GCP and Firestore exist in the same scope. My server runs on GCP docker, so I'm hoping to import Firestore API's in GCP or vice-versa

Comment: @Enigma it depends, when there is no need to pull in further values (or write back values) from/to the Datastore (eg. when using HTTP triggers), it does not require any service account to access the Datastore... however, when using Pub/Sub, it might be the least complicated when it would be running under a service account: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication

Comment: @Enigma here it is also explained: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts you'd need a service account with roles Datastore & Pub/Sub assigned (depending what the script shall be able to access); also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112189/how-to-access-cloud-datastore-from-apps-script-with-a-service-account/49113976#49113976
those are the Firebase Node.js packages available: https://www.npmjs.com/~firebase-ops ...in particular `firebase-functions`.

Comment: commands are `gcloud functions --help` & `gcloud beta functions --help`.