# How to get the device token only once the user downloads the application?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

I have a cloud function that listens to the Firebase storage, whenever I upload a document, it listens to it, and update the Firestore based on the data provided from the document.

Now, **I want to notify the user every time I upload a document**, so what I did is I added the functionality of the push notification inside the same cloud function, and created a service that gets the device token, stores in a a device collection, loop through the collection and send the notification.

The problem i am having is, every time the app is opened, the writes in my Firstore is incremented by 1, I assume it is coming from the wrong implementation of the notification.

I am supposed to write the token only once the user download the app, but it seems that it is writing every time the app is initialized.

I can see that I am calling the function whenever the app is initialized, i tried to check with an if statement if the token already exists, and return nothing if it does, otherwise write it to the collection, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

this is my cloud function:

```
exports.addFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(object => {
    if (object && object.name) {


     ........... // perform the initial process

        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Data is stored');
            setTimeout(async () => {
                // SEND NOTIFICATION 
                //NOTIFICATION CONTENT 
                const payLoad = {
                    notification: {
                        title: 'New Cat',
                        body: `Check it out!`,
                        sound: 'Enabled'
                    },
                }
                // COLLECTION REFERENCE
                const colRef = db.collection('Devices');

                // device reference 
             const deviceRef = colRef.where('userId', '==','testUserId');

                // get users tokens and send notification 
                const devices = await deviceRef.get();
                const tokens: any = [];

                //loop over documents 
                devices.forEach(result => {
                    const token = result.data().token;
                    tokens.push(token);
                });
                console.log('tokens', tokens);

                //Send Notifications 
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, 
                 payLoad).then(response => {
                    // check if there is an error for each message 
                    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
                    const error = result.error;
                      if (error) {
                            console.error('Failure sending notification 
                             to', tokens[index], error);
                        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid- 
                         registration-token' ||
                          error.code === 'messaging/registration- 
                          token-not-registered') {
                        colRef.doc(tokens[index]).delete().then(() => {
                         console.log(tokens[index], 'have been deleted');
                               }).catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                })
                            }

                        }
                    })
                })
            }, 5000);

        })
    } 
   }
    return;
}
);
```

This is my notification service:

```
  // GET TOKEN
  async getToken() {
    let token;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      token = await this.firebase.getToken();
      console.log('token', token);
    }
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
     token = await this.firebase.getToken();
     await this.firebase.grantPermission();
   }

    this.saveToken(token);
  }

 private saveToken(token) {
   if (!token) { return; }

   const devicesRef = this.afs.collection('Devices');

   const data = {
     token,
   };
   if (token === devicesRef.doc(token)) {
     return;
   } else {
     return devicesRef.doc(token).set(data);
   }
  }

  onNotifications() {
  return this.firebase.onMessageReceived();
 }
```

And finally, the code in app.ts:

```
  private async presentToast(message) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message,
      duration: 3000
    });
    toast.present();
    }
    private notificationSetup() {
    this.nS.getToken();
    this.nS.onNotifications().subscribe(
      (msg) => {
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.presentToast(msg.aps.alert);
        } else {
          this.presentToast(msg.body);
        }
      });
   }

initializeApp(){
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
   this.splashScreen.hide();
   this.notificationSetup();
   timer(3000).subscribe(() => {
    this.showSplash = false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can find two things here:

1. You want your users to know when you upload a file.
2. You want to store your token only when an user downloads the app, but it's stored every time the app is opened.

I can help with the first one.

This sounds to me like you want to use Triggers. [Check this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451462/7674214), I think is similar of what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I got the first one figured already, the only issue I am having is with number 2.
I am not sure if the tokens are supposed to be written once or if they expire and are wirtten everytime the app is initialized.